# Get a list of key's in HashMap having key like 'some value'

Tags: java, hashmap

In Mysql we can query a table having clause " **WHERE name LIKE '%someName%'** ", can we have the same functionality with HashMap in java,if so how can we achieve this more efficiently in a less time by **not iterating** over each element?

Comment: just loop with some regex, or create your own map impl

Comment: Is "name" the key or the value in your map? Would you like to return a list of keys or values?

Comment: "name" is a key in a map

Comment: How efficient do you want it to be? You can do a brute force search of  HashMap, or you can use a NavigableMap efficiently, but the code is far more complicated. i.e. if a brute force search isn't obvious to you, don't attempt using a NavigableMap.

Comment: I need to search for key in a large number of keys more frequently

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can iterate on all your keys and check if they match a regexp. This might not be the most efficient way of doing it, but it's the first thing I thought of. 
Here is what it would look like:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("*someName*"); // the regexp you want to match

List<String> matchingKeys = new ArrayList<>();
for (String key : map.keySet()) {
    if(p.matcher(key).matches()) {
        matchingKeys.add(key);
    }
}

// matchingKeys now contains the keys that match the regexp
```

Note: `map` is supposed to be declared earlier like this:

```
HashMap<String, SomeValueClass> map = new HashMap<>();
```

Comment: This will upto my need functionality wise, but i am thinking about large set of key values which has to be iterated large number of times

Comment: @achuth Then why not use a real database? How much memory your program will need anyway if the number of keys is that large?

Comment: Actually i get all keys from a column in a table from database, of size 62Kb

Comment: @achuth Then why don't you use the `LIKE` SQL keyword when you get the info? I think it will be more efficient than loading everything in memory and iterate on everything many times in a row.

Comment: All the key are stored in JSON format in a single row of a single coumn

Comment: Hash map is faster in getting a value than iterating over a list or array by comparing each element, if there is no way in doing this i would directly use a array rather than a HashMap

Comment: @achuth Storing JSON in a database does not seem a good idea to me, why would you do such a thing? You might want to re-design your DB tables to fit the JSON fields. Then, you can load your stuff in a HashMap (if it fits in your memory) for indivual value accesses, and do SQL queries for large regexp accesses.

Comment: @achuth Here is some wise advice on whether to store JSON or not in the DB: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15367769/1540818

Answer (score 9):

If you're using Java SE 8 and the new Streams API: there is a [filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) method which basically is what you are looking for, I think.

e.g. something like (untested!):

```
myMap.entrySet().stream().filter(entry -> entry.getKey().contains("someName")).map(entry -> entry.getValue()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thank you @Puce! I just needed the key part, so `myMap.entrySet().stream().filter(entry -> entry.getKey().contains("someName")).collect(Collectors.toList());` was enough

Answer (score 2):

Remove all values which doesn't contain key part:

```
yourMap.keySet().removeIf(key -> !key.contains(keyPart));
```

Or regex:

```
yourMap.keySet().removeIf(key -> !key.matches(".*keyPart.*"));
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be a way to achieve this functionality in Java, but `HashMap` will not do it.

Comment: I too want the way to achieve this, can you show some code samples

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all the values in a map that are associated to a given key you are doing a *reverse lookup*.

You would need to iterate over every key / value pair in the map, searching for the given value and storing it into a collection. Something like this:

```
List<KeyType> keys = new ArrayList<>();
for (Map.Entry<KeyType, ValueType> e : myMap)
    if(e.getValue().equals(valueWeAreSearchingFor)) keys.add(e.getKey());
```

Comment: What happens when searching a map having some 1000's  of key's frequently?

Comment: This might not meet the OP's needs, because he wanted to match a pattern, not an exact value.

Comment: @achuth Well, you have to iterate over the entire map, so it's going to be *slow*. Consider using something like a [BidiMap](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/BidiMap.html)

Comment: @Joffrey True, I didn't get that part of the question. Your answer is better then, upvoting.