# Disadvantages of storing all the columns inside a JSON column

Tags: json, database, laravel

what are the disadvantages of storing all the columns of a table inside a single JSON column ?

e.g for a user table instead of having this

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('firstname');
        $table->string('lastname');
        $table->string('username')->unique();
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->timestamps();            
        $table->rememberToken();
    });
```

Just do this

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
    $table->json('attributes'); // contains all the fields
        $table->timestamps();   
        $table->rememberToken();
    });
```

**Update**

So in brief,  this approach isn't good for products with customized properties for example.
NoSql Databases are optimal for e-commerce website / systems.

but JSON field can be useful for combining less used fields like gender, age, address.

true?

Comment: Hope my conclusion is right.
Using JSON for all fields is adding extra layer and effort on data.
Moreover, it would be like using SQL for another purpose from what it is intended to, so if all fields are replaced with JSON better to go with NoSQL database. In the end it is all about business requirements which database type should we choose.

Comment: You can query JSON and there are many JSON functions, the downside is that it is unstructured, so probably the same downsides as the schema less databases.
https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/json-with-mariadb-10-2/

Answer (score 2):

- You can't query the json data
- You get a long ugly string until you deserialize it
- You will manually handle the json column content during fetching/inserting i.e encoding and decoding, this results in consuming server resources.

Answer (score 1):

You can't cast correctly the data. Querying and filtering the json could be painful, you can't use foreign keys, if you save ids from other tables, not so good if you make a mistake and delete al the column, you'll lost all the data instead of working column by column.

Look at this two answers:

[Storing JSON in database vs. having a new column for each key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15367696/storing-json-in-database-vs-having-a-new-column-for-each-key/15368439)

[Is there any advantage/disadvantage of storing field value as a JSON array rather than creating new table and one-to-many relationship bet them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23709966/is-there-any-advantage-disadvantage-of-storing-field-value-as-a-json-array-rathe)

Answer (score 0):

There are so many disadvantages but I would like to mention three.

1. You are not going to be able of query through sql the data of yor table in a clean way.
2. You have to handle the entity data by your own, consuming server resources.
3. Storing your data in that way is more susceptible to corruption due to the parsing process and manual handling.

This is not the purpose of sql storing.
Maybe you can explor options like document based data bases like MongoDb