# How to save Kinetic.Layer to JSON and load it in another existing layer?

Tags: json, kineticjs

I have an empty layer (not really empty, I have drawn a grid there, so there's lines and rectangles), and another layer similar to the first layer, where I dragged and dropped multiple shapes and images. What I want to do is:

- Save the second layer (called rightLayer) using `toJSON()`: done!
- Draw the saved JSON in the first layer, and save it again : not yet, because..

In the docs, I should do this :

```
var json = rightLayer.toJSON();
var layer1 = Kinetic.Node.create(json, 'container');
```

Whereas I don't want to actually *create* the layer, it's already there, I just need to draw on it. How do I do it without creating a variable?

A second question: Can JSON format be saved in database? I'll need to store the JSON in order to display it later.

Answer (score 1):

Answering your 2nd question, there are a few databases that use JSON storage, or in other words, document-oriented storage. Examples of those databases are: [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) and [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/). Im currently using MongoDB in my project and it seems to be a very powerful and complete database.

Comment: I'm using microsoft SQL server DB (the DB tables exist) and I'm thinking about adding a row to a table. Is it feasible or it's necessary to use another database?

Comment: I would like to suggest reading this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15367696/storing-json-in-database-vs-having-a-new-row-for-each-key). The answers there provide a good overview regarding the non-relational and relational models.

Comment: Maybe the way to do it, since I'm limited by the database, is storing json in a xml data type in Microsoft DB and then use Json.NET framework (still don't know it) to convert from json to xml and vice versa. Not sure yet, I just searched. Thanks for the reply :)