# How to get JSON type as JSON instead of String from Nodejs Mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, mysql-5.7

I have table say TEST(id INT, attribute JSON) in MySQL 5.7

When I try to query the table in Nodejs using mysql package as follows

```
con.query("select * from TEST where id=?", [req.params.id], function (err, results) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(results);
  });
```

I get the following output

```
[
   {
        "id": 2,
        "package": "{\"tag\": \"tag1\", \"item\": \"item1\"}"
    }
]
```

Is there a way to get the package item in the above result as JSON object instead of a string without iterating the array and do JSON.parse to convert string to JSON?

Expected Output

```
[
       {
            "id": 2,
            "package": {"tag": "tag1", 
                        "item": "item1"}
        }
    ]
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Is there a way to get the package item in the above result as JSON
>   object instead of a string without iterating the array and do
>   JSON.parse to convert string to JSON?

MySQL 5.7 supports [JSON data type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html), so you can change package type to `JSON` and you won't have to iterate and perform `JSON.parse` on each row, if your client has support for this data type.

Have in mind that [mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) package does not support it, but [mysql2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2) does.

```
CREATE TABLE `your-table` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `package` json DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Now package will be an array/object:

```
con.query("select * from TEST where id=?", [req.params.id], function (err, results) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(results[0].package.tag); // tag1 using mysql2
    console.log(results[0].package.item); // item1 using mysql2
});
```

In case you're running a MySQL version lower than 5.7 or you don't want to use the `JSON` type, you will need to iterate and parse it yourself.

You can use this one liner:

```
results = results.map(row => (row.package = JSON.parse(row.package), row));
```

If you want to know if you should or shouldn't store JSON in a relational database there's a nice discussion in this question:

[Storing JSON in database vs. having a new column for each key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15367696/storing-json-in-database-vs-having-a-new-column-for-each-key?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Thanks Marcos for the reply. I am using the JSON as the data type as mentioned in my question.  The results from mysql query node module are automatically converted to STRING by default i.e I can't access directly as JSON object. I need to do JSON.parse(results[0].package)...

Comment: @Deepan check my updated answer, you have to use `mysql2` package! And you didn't mention you were using JSON data type.

Comment: Thanks Marcus. mysql2 package did the work. I replaced mysql with mysql2 node package.

Comment: The key was mysql2 package for as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

This is a slight variation on Tanner's answer but, if you're using the node `mysql` library and you've defined fields in the database using MySQL's JSON data type, you can use "type casting" when initially setting up the connection to convert any JSON-typed value returned by any query to a JSON object:

```
let connection = mysql.createConnection(
  {typeCast: function (field, next) {
    if (field.type === "JSON") {
      return JSON.parse(field.string());
    } else {
      return next();
    }
  }}
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a typeCast function to your mysql connection/pool. In my case, I want to convert all longtext fields to JSON if possible. In the case it fails, you will still get the original value.

```
let auth = {database:'db', password:'pw', user:'u', host:'host.com' };
auth.typeCast = function(field, next) {
    if (field.type == 'BLOB' && field.length == 4294967295) {
        let value = field.string();
        try {
            return JSON.parse(value);
        } catch (e) {
            return value;
        }
    }
    return next();
};
let connection = mysql.createConnection(auth);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use package [mysql2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2) instead of `mysql`. It will parse the result by default.

Answer (score -2):

I think all you need to do is `JSON.parse(results)`

```
con.query("select * from TEST where id=?", [req.params.id], function (err, results) {
if (err) throw err;
console.log(JSON.parse(results));
```

});

EDIT! commenter noted that you need to iterate through results, my answer was hasty and wouldn't work:

```
con.query("select * from TEST where id=?", [req.params.id], function (err, results) {
if (err) throw err;
results = results.map(row => (row.package = JSON.parse(row.package), row));
```

});

Comment: `results` is already an array, that won't work. He has to iterate and `JSON.parse` each package.

Comment: still won't work :P, you need to use `JSON.parse` on each row `package`. so `results = results.map(row => (row.package = JSON.parse(row.package), row))`

Comment: Got ahead of myself, @MarcosCasagrande, ty