# fetch an array and loop

Tags: php, mysql

target value in column `db`:

`["html", "css", "xml", "json"]`

**php**

```
$sql = "select tabs from t1 where db = 'link' limit 1";
$st = $db->prepare($sql);
$st->execute();
$arr = $st->fetch();
$tabs = "";
foreach ($arr as $el) {
    $tabs .= "<div class='tableft'>" . $el . "</div>\n";
}
echo $tabs;
```

Result:

```
<div class='tableft'>["html", "css", "xml", "json"]</div>
<div class='tableft'>["html", "css", "xml", "json"]</div>
```

What I need:

```
<div class='tableft'>html</div>
<div class='tableft'>css</div>
<div class='tableft'>xml</div>
<div class='tableft'>json</div>
```

Comment: Do not store values as csv. learn about normalization

Comment: @Jens, this is a json array (column is not a json type).

Comment: Why you store the json in the db?

Comment: Yep, that's not CSV but don't store JSON neither

Comment: @AymDev, afaik json is in fact - text data. Why don't store them inside a database?

Comment: As Jens said: *"learn about normalization"*. This data should be 4 rows. As it is, as you know it is JSON, just parse it.

Comment: This is an interesting post about JSON in MySQL databases: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15367696/storing-json-in-database-vs-having-a-new-column-for-each-key

Comment: I too would like to know: why not store JSON in a DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to parse your json data to array and loop through it inside loop like this.

```
$sql = "select tabs from t1 where db = 'link' limit 1";
$st = $db->prepare($sql);
$st->execute();
$arr = $st->fetch();
$tabs = "";
foreach ($arr as $el) {
    $results = json_decode($el);
    foreach($results as $result) {
       $tabs .= "<div class='tableft'>" . $result . "</div>\n";
    }
}
echo $tabs;
```