# What are the advantages and disadvantages of storing data as JSON in an RDBMS?

Tags: json, database, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I have a database table (in Postgresql) in which I have one column as JSON where I store a bunch of key value pairs. A friend looked at my schema and suggested I store these key value pairs in a separate table instead of storing it as a JSON object, especially if I want to perform search operations in future.

I used JSON because the key value pairs in the JSON object can vary with time. The number of key-value pairs as well as the key-value pairs themselves.

His suggestions are mainly based on two facts.

1. I do have plans to perform searches on at least one of the fields in this JSON object that I am storing currently.
2. I want to make the schema as generic as possible so that I have as many options as possible when I am thinking about a database migration with minimal changes required to the back-end code, which happens to Java with JPA Hibernate

I agree with my friend. But before making the changes, I would like to fully understand the advantages and disadvantages of using JSON in a relational database management system. General answers as well as answers suiting my particular use case are welcome.

Comment: For simple JSONs (with  key value pairs within a level of depth 1 or 2), it is generally easier to manipulate and extract data using built-in PostgreSQL [json functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html). But, it gets harder ( queries get more complex to write and maintain) when multiple layers of data needs to be retrieved / modified based on filters, which would otherwise be much simpler if they're structured as standard relational tables  with appropriate columns.The bottom line is that you must prefer a fine balance and not expand the scope of json data in RDBMS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Storing JSON in database vs. having a new column for each key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15367696/storing-json-in-database-vs-having-a-new-column-for-each-key)

Comment: @ggorlen Yes, it does give a fairly good insight. Thank you. :-)