# JsonArray saving along with escape characters in database while using java

Tags: java, json, java-8

I am converting `modelObject` to `JSON` string and inserting the same JSON string to `JSONArray` object. Here is what I am doing.Here `jsonArray` is of type `org.json.JSONArray`.Here is a detail list of steps I am doing:

```
  String configuration= dtoObject.getConfig();
  JSONArray configJsonArray = new JSONArray(configuration);
 // get modelObject from configJsonArray
 //do some operations on  modelObject
  String myJson = JsonUtils.toJson(modelObject); 
  jsonArray.put(0, myJson); //insert it back to json array
  dtoObject.setConfig(jsonArray.toString());
  myRepository.save(dtoObject)
```

I need to convert the `jsonArray` object as String to set as property to `dtoObject`. So that is why I am converting `jsonArray` to String  When I am seeing in debug mode in my IDE, the `jsonArray` object after converting to String is looking like this:

```
["{\"foo\":\"bar\"}]
```

It is also being stored in same format in the database. I don't want the escape characters to be saved to database. How do I do this?

Comment: Can you share what is `jsonArray` and it's `toString` method.

Comment: What is JSOUtils.toJso ()? What is modelObject?

Comment: What would you *expect* the JSON to look like? Bear in mind that without the escape characters, it wouldn't be valid JSON: `["{"foo":"bar"}]` for example simply isn't valid. You're encoding a model as a JSON string, then including that JSON string in a JSON array - so you're encoding as JSON twice. Are you sure you want to do that?

Comment: *Plus* if you're decided upon the need for the storage to be in JSON, some of the open source RDBMS offerings have [direct support for JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15367696/storing-json-in-database-vs-having-a-new-column-for-each-key#15367769)

Comment: @JonSkeet I need to  get the model object from jsonArray object and do some modifications on the model object and again insert the same updated object back to jsonArray.In the database, the modelObject is stored as JSON only

Comment: @kondasurekha: So why does that mean converting the model to a JSON string and putting *that* into the array? Your array doesn't contain a JSON object, it contains a *string*. It's unclear why you're doing that - I *suspect* you don't want to. (I would strongly recommend clarifying your question, including a [mcve].)

Answer (score 0):

As @JonSkeet mentioned in comments , you are inserting `String` object into `JSONArray` . Try changing the  `String` to `JSONObject` and insert into `JSONArray`. Try something like this:

```
 JSONObject myJsonObject= new JSONObject(myJson); //convert json string to json object
jsonArray.put(0, myJsonObject);
```